# How to remove submitted rows on Angular-xeditable table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

This is my first time using Angular-Xeditable in my app. I ran into a problem trying to figure out how to remove an x-editable row that was added or modified and then submitted with the save button into an object that was accessed through a `ng-repeat` loop.

If I change the value of a row and then save it, I am not be able to remove the row from my table. If I press the remove button, the row is deleted from my object in the scope using the `array.splice(index,1)` function, but is not removed from my table.

in my html I have:

```js
modalInst.saveActivity = function(data) {
            console.log('Saving Activity: ' + data);
        };

        modalInst.removeActivity = function(index) {
            modalInst.pendingActivities.splice(index,1);
        };

        modalInst.addActivity = function() {
            modalInst.inserted = {
                name: '',
                description: '',
                completed: false,
                isNew: true
            };
            modalInst.pendingActivities.push(modalInst.inserted);
        };

        modalInst.checkActivityName = function(data) {
            if(!data) {
                return "";
            }
        };

        modalInst.checkActivityDescription = function(data) {
            if(!data) {
                return "";
            }
        };

        modalInst.activityList = [];
        prospectSvc.getBudget(modalInst.client).then(function(budget){
            console.log("Budget", budget);
            modalInst.activityList = budget.product.tasks;
        });

        modalInst.showActivityList = function(activity) {
            var selected = [];
            if(activity.name) {
                selected = $filter('filter')(modalInst.activityList, {name: activity.name});
            }
            return selected.length ? selected[0].name : 'Not set';
        };
```

```html
<button type="button" ng-click="visitModalCtrl.addActivity()" ng-disabled="!visitModalCtrl.editable" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Nueva tarea<br/><br/>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover bg-white">
    <tr style="font-weight: bold">
      <td style="width:50%">Tarea</td>
      <td style="width:35%">Descripci&oacute;n</td>
      <td style="width:5%"></td>
      <td style="width:10%"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="pendingActivity in visitModalCtrl.pendingActivities" ng-form="" editable-form="" name="rowform" onbeforesave="visitModalCtrl.saveActivity($data)" shown="visitModalCtrl.inserted == pendingActivity">
      <td><span editable-select="pendingActivity.name" e-name="name" e-form="rowform" e-ng-options="act.name as act.name for act in visitModalCtrl.activityList">{{ visitModalCtrl.showActivityList(pendingActivity) }}</span></td>
      <td><span editable-text="pendingActivity.description" e-name="description" e-form="rowform" onbeforesave="visitModalCtrl.checkActivityDescription($data)" e-required="">{{ pendingActivity.description || &apos;empty&apos; }}</span></td>
      <td><span ng-if="!pendingActivity.completed" e-name="completed" e-form="rowform" class="fa fa-clock-o"></span><span ng-if="pendingActivity.completed" e-name="completed" e-form="rowform" class="fa fa-check-circle"></span></td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <form editable-form="" name="rowform" class="form-buttons form-inline"></form>
        <div ng-show="rowform.$visible" class="buttons">
          <button type="submit" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting || pendingActivity.completed || !visitModalCtrl.editable" ng-click="rowform.$submit()" title="Save" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"><em class="fa fa-save"></em></button>
          <button type="button" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting || pendingActivity.completed || !visitModalCtrl.editable" ng-click="rowform.$cancel()" title="Cancel" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><em class="fa fa-times"></em></button>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="!rowform.$visible" class="buttons">
          <button ng-click="rowform.$show()" title="Edit" ng-disabled="pendingActivity.completed || !visitModalCtrl.editable" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"><em class="fa fa-pencil"></em></button>
          <button ng-click="visitModalCtrl.removeActivity($index)" title="Delete" ng-disabled="pendingActivity.completed || !visitModalCtrl.editable" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><em class="fa fa-trash"></em></button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</button>
```

How do you just delete the row that was edited or added from the table?

Comment: Its actually very simple, don't know why you are getting trouble.share some code so that we will solve it

Comment: Thanks for the answer, here is my html code and my controller code

Comment: I think you are not clling your `removeActivity` method properly